# chartnew.js - remove lines from pie chart on 100%

Tags: jquery, chart.js, chartnew.js

is there a way to remove the unnecessary line from the pie in this case? im using [chartnew.js](https://github.com/FVANCOP/ChartNew.js/wiki/070_030_Pie)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `segmentShowStroke` option to false, like so

```
new Chart(document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")).Pie(data, {
    segmentShowStroke: false
});
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks. any chance i can keep the circle border?

Comment: There's no direct option. But you could draw a circle around it once the animation is complete.

Comment: what about remove the border but keep the lines inside?

Comment: pretty much same thing. turn the setting to true and draw a whie border to hide the circle.